# Which ANOVA should I use?

Tags: self-study, anova, two-way

Let's say I have a problem where there are two distinct groups, and within each groups, there are two more groups, leading to a total of four groups.  So it's something like this:

[image]

I want to run five tests.

- The total difference between test and control.
- The difference between A and B within test/control.  This would be the difference between TA and TB.  Also the difference between CA and CB.
- The difference between A in test and A in control.  This would be the difference between TA and CA.
- The difference between B in test and B in control.  This would be the difference between TB and CB.

Which ANOVA or technique should I use?

Comment: Without more details about the design and randomization, could be a two way ANOVA with interaction, or a nested design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into a two-way anova with an interaction, since you are interested in both

> The difference between A and B within test/control. This would be the
> difference between TA and TB. Also the difference between CA and CB.

and the corresponding

> The difference between A in test and A in control. This would be the
> difference between TA and CA.

and

> The difference between B in test and B in control. This would be the
> difference between TB and CB,

this does not look like a nested design, but you really should tell us more.